# includes() functions doesn't works

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities

I'm using EF 6 and Code First, but for some reason when i'm trying to collect a list of ICBs from database the dependences (Station for exemple) is not return as a filled object (icb.station), only the stations IDs. I have this relations.

public class ICB
    {

```
    public ICB()
    {
        ICBResources = new List<ICBResource>();
    }

    public int ICBId { get; set; }

    public int LevelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Station Station { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOfCall { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStarted { get; set; }

    public Staff IncidentCommander { get; set; }
    public Staff OperationsCommander { get; set; }
    public Staff SectorCommander { get; set; }
    public Staff SectorCommander2 { get; set; }
    public Staff CommandSupportOfficer { get; set; }
    public Staff SafetyOfficer { get; set; }
    public Staff CommunicationsOfficer { get; set; }
    public Staff WaterOfficer { get; set; }
    public Staff BAOfficer { get; set; }
    public Staff HazmatOfficer { get; set; }



    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

**What should I do to bring all this members filled ?** they are coming up with IDs only.
I'm using .Include() but doesn't works.

```
    public List<ICB> GetAllICBs(Company company, Station station = null)
    {
        if (station != null)
        {
            return GetDbSet<ICB>()
                .Include("ICBResources")
                .Include("Station")
                .Where(i => i.Company.CompanyId == company.CompanyId 
                    && i.Station.StationId == station.StationId)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.TimeStarted).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return GetDbSet<ICB>()
                .Include("ICBResources")
                .Include("Station")
                .Where(i => i.Company.CompanyId == company.CompanyId)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.TimeStarted).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi is GetDbSet method in from your repository ? If yes probably it returns data without related table, you should use Include earlier in you repository ie:

```
IQueryable icb = db.ICB.Include("ICBResources");
```

Comment: It's my dbContext

`protected TargetDbContext Context
        {
            get { return (TargetDbContext) UnitOfWork; }
        }

        protected virtual DbSet<TEntity> GetDbSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>();
        }`

Comment: So you need to create custom repository for ICB otherwise is not going to work

Comment: I created that. This method GetAllICBs its from that. I have this .Include() works well for others situations and works wel. I checked my models but for some reason only in ICBs doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

The name of my property on include method was wrong.

Thanks for your help.